# What is the shortest, accurate, and cross-browser compatible method for reading a cookie in go?

Tags: go

hi iam doing signup function so,I need a function that should read all cookies from browser and it should cross-browser compatible

Comment: The HTTP-protocol should be cross-browser-compatible enough (at least I hope so..)

Comment: To ask a good question you should explain what you want to achieve. And provide the needed details for the helpers, to understand your issue and provide valuable answer. Try to elaborate you question, please.

Answer (score 0):

Undoable.
The browser **sends** back to the server the cookies on each *HTTP* request. There is absolutely no other way, on the server side, to "read" cookies from a browser.

For the nitpickers: You can make the browser execute JavaScript which can read *some* cookies and send them back actively, but this will give you less cookies (the non HttpOnly ones) than a normal browser response.

Accessing cookies in a browser through security holes is clearly not cross-browser compatible.